# php71w-xml is install but i still have this error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in

Tags: php, centos

I have install php71w-xml but im still getting this error :

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in**

my operating system is centos7.

Comment: Please note that i have restarted apache but still get that error .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the default php version on the server is php-7.1.x? do a `rpm -qa | grep php` and see what packages are installed. Also check `/etc/php.d/`, see if there is any .ini file that is supposed to load the xml php extesion/module.

You could also issue a `php -i` and then check for xml or create a `info.php` file with this content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Place somewhere like in /var/www/html or wherever your apache root folder is and try accessing it in a web browser and check the php info output there and see if xml extension is actually loaded.